# How can I partition a set of words given pairs that must end up together?

Tags: text-processing, awk, algorithms

I have a space or comma separated table with two columns, each row representing equivalence of the two words.

```
A B  
B C  
B D  
C E  
F G
```

What I want is a table with each row listing all mutually equivalent words.

```
A B C D E  
F G
```

That is if two words ever occur on the same row of input they must end up in the same row of the output.

Any tool would do.

Comment: Is `A B D C E` also correct for the first line?

Comment: I guess you need this done recursively, right? I mean, `D` and `E` will only be in the first row after having been added by processing the previous rows. What if you have `E G` further down? How should that be dealt with? Also, which is it, space or comma?

Comment: why aren't F and G in the first row?

Comment: @terdon yes it has to be done recursively.

Comment: @artm Because A = B, B = C, C = D, and D = E so these all should come in one line. F & G are different so this goes to new line or another line. Kindly help guys.

Comment: ah, each line of output contains words that ever occur together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, start with the input file as an argument:

```
import sys

res = []  # list of lists
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    try:
        x, y = line.split()  # split on space
    except ValueError:
        line = line.rstrip()
        x, y = line.split(',')  # retry with comma
    for l in res:
        if x in l:
            if y not in l:
                l.append(y)
            break
    else:
        res.append([x, y])

for line in res:
    print ' '.join(line)
```

The test `if y not in l:` skips adding the same value twice, I am not sure if that is wanted, or if the source has such anomalies. You can leave out the test and always execute `l.append(y)`.

The code tries to split on space first, then retries comma. This assumes comma separated lines have no space in them (i.e. are not `A, B`).

The nested `for` loop uses (AFAIK) a python particularity: the `else` is only executed if the `for` loop ends through exhaustion, that is not through the break statement. This means if `x` is not found, the pair is appended as new list to `res`.

Comment: yes...I am new to Stackexchange. I do not know how to say accept the answer and close the thread.

Comment: @Vinay No problem. To click just click on the smaller v like sign below the down arrow next to the number (currently 1) next to this question.

Comment: Hey @Anthon... I am in little trouble again. Seems like you script is not working properly or it is not giving the expected result. May be I was not able explain the problem properly. Should I start a new thread or can I post it here again?

Comment: @Vinay just extend/refine your question. Show clearly with what input the program goes wrong ( we need at least the input and the expected output, the erroneous output I can generate with the program ;-) Then leave me short comment here, because I get notified of that comment but not from when you edit your question, and I will look at it.

Comment: @Anthon, your script will leave a newline in the last word of a line split on commas. It also suffers from the problem my previous version had (not merging sets once created)

Comment: @artm You were right, updated

Answer (score 2):

## theory

This problem is known as [partitioning a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) into [equivalence classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), with input file listing pairwise equivalences. It can be solved with the help of a [disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure.

Less abstract example is e.g. partitioning words into groups of synonyms given pairs of synonyms:

```
large big
big great
great vast
small little
little tiny
```

becomes:

```
large big great vast
small little tiny
```

## ruby solution

Disjoint set isn't available in ruby standard library, so I emulate it using a ruby `Hash` (known elsewhere as "associative array", "dictionary", "map").

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# new elements end up in "singleton subsets"
subsets = Hash.new { |subsets, element| subsets[element] = [element] }
ARGF.each do |line|
  x, y = line.scan(/[^\s,]/)
  # these two emulate disjoint-set's "find" operation
  x_set = subsets[x]
  y_set = subsets[y]
  # and this loop implements disjoint-set's "union"
  y_set.each do |element, _|
    subsets[element] = x_set << element
  end unless x_set == y_set
end
puts subsets.values.uniq.map{|set| set.join(" ")}
```

## usage

this expects filenames on the command line or data on stdin:

```shell
$ ruby so-162730.rb input.txt
A B C D E
F G

$ ruby so-162730.rb < input.txt
A B C D E
F G
```

## awk solution

Perhaps more appropriate for this site.

Here I use a slightly different implementation of disjoint-set: each subset is represented by one of its elements ("leader"). This makes union operation slower, but is easier to implement with awk's simple data types.

```awk
{
  union(find($1), find($2));
}

END {
  format_subsets();
  for(i in subsets)
    print subsets[i];
}

function find(element) {
  if (!leaders[element])
    leaders[element] = element;
  return leaders[element];
}

function union(leader_1, leader_2) {
  for(i in leaders)
    if (leaders[i] == leader_2)
      leaders[i] = leader_1;
}

function format_subsets() {
  for(element in leaders) {
    leader = leaders[element]
    subsets[leader] = (subset = subsets[leader]) ? (subset OFS element) : element;
  }
}
```

## usage

```shell
$ awk -f so-162730.awk < input.txt
A B C D E
F G
```

Or for whitespace or comma separated input:

```
$ awk -f so-162730.awk -F '[[:space:]]+|,' input.txt
A B C D E
F G
```